# How to modify this Haskell square root function to take an array

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a function that will take and int and return its square root. However now i want to modify it so that it takes an array of integers and gives back an array with the square roots of the elements of the first array. I know Haskell does not use loops so how can this modification be done? Thanks.

```
intSquareRoot :: Int -> Int
intSquareRoot n = try n where
  try i   | i*i > n   = try (i - 1) 
          | i*i <= n  = i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Don't.

The idea of “looping through some collection”, putting each result in the corresponding slot of its input, is a somewhat trivial, extremely common pattern. Patterns are for OO programmers. In Haskell, when there's a pattern, we want to *abstract* over it, i.e. give it a simple name that we can always re-use without extra boilerplate.

This particular “pattern” is the *functor* operation<sup>1</sup>. For lists it's called

```
map :: (a->b) -> [a]->[b]
```

more generally (e.g. it'll also work with real arrays; lists aren't actually arrays),

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a->b) -> f a->f b
```

So instead of defining an extra function

```
intListSquareRoot :: [Int] -> [Int]
intListSquareRoot = ...
```

you simply use `map intSquareRoot` right where you wanted to use that function.

Of course, you could also define that “lifted” version of `intSquareRoot`,

```
intListSquareRoot = map intSquareRoot
```

but that gains you practically nothing over simply inlining the `map` call right where you need it.

---

### If you insist

That said... it's of course valid to wonder how `map` itself works. Well, you can manually “loop” through a list by recursion:

```
map' :: (a->b) -> [a]->[b]
map' _ [] = []
map' f (x:xs) = f x : map' f xs
```

Now, you could inline your specific function here

```
intListSquareRoot' :: [Int] -> [Int]
intListSquareRoot' [] = []
intListSquareRoot' (x:xs) = intSquareRoot x : intListSquareRoot' xs
```

This is not only much more clunky and awkward than quickly inserting the `map` magic word, it will also often be slower: compilers such as GHC can make better optimisations when they work on higher-level concepts<sup>2</sup> such as folds, than when they have to work again and again with manually defined recursion.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Not to be confused what many C++ programmers call a “[functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)”. Haskell uses the word in the [correct mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), which comes from category theory.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>This is why languages such as Matlab and APL actually achieve decent performance for special applications, although they are dynamically-typed, interpreted languages: they have this special case of “vector looping” hard-coded into their very syntax. (Unfortunately, this is pretty much the *only* thing they can do well...)</sub>

Comment: So would it look something like thi?
intListSquareRoot :: [Int] -> [Int]
intListSquareRoot n = try n where
  try i   | i*i > n   = try (i - 1) 
          | i*i <= n  = i

Comment: @Chalupa No, there's an `intListSquareRoot :: [Int] -> [Int]` already defined in this answer.

Comment: @Chalupa This answer suggests that you should _not_ define `intListSquareRoot` at all -- you can directly use the original function and `map`: for instance `map intSquareRoot [16,36,25]` returns `[4,6,5]`.

Comment: @cirdec i know i was talking about what my function would look like

Comment: @Chalupa You've already defined `intSquareRoot`. Leave it alone. If you need to *change* something you've already made to do something else, you are probably doing something wrong. Ask yourself, is there anything wrong about the design of `intSquareRoot`? No, it's about as simple as possible; there's nothing wrong with it. That means you should be looking for a way to *reuse* it rather than trying to *change* it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map`:

```
arraySquareRoot = map intSquareRoot
```

Comment: where would i need to write this line?

Comment: @Chalupa: It's another function definition, so, I guess, wherever you're defining functions.

Comment: I don't understand this solution because intSquareRoot takes an int, so how can i use map with something that's only an int?

Comment: @Chalupa: `map` take a function and a list, and applies the function to each element in the list (returning a new list). So if you pass `arraySquareRoot` a list of ints, then map will apply `intSquareRoot` to each element of that list (an int).